# ECS Fargate with ALB challenges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am currently exploring AWS ECS with Fargate. At first, I thought that it is a good feature that can do autoscaling and save cost, as well as without server maintenance overhead.

But when I look further onto it, the more I see the pain into it.

1. Fargate does not provide static IP, and the recommendation is to use ALB. ALB alone is costing plenty of money.
2. ALB doing health check interval and thus Fargate rarely sleeps due to ALB (and thus incurring more charges then it should)

My question is:

1. Anyone have an alternative of dealing with issue (1) and (2)? a way that can overcome it for cost saving purposes and at the same time retaining an elastic IP
2. If ALB is forwarded to Fargate with IP address, what happen if IP ECS (Fargate) IP got restarted? Will ALB auto detect it or what are the way to detect Fargate IP changes and update back to ALB automatically, and if not, how to handle such situation where the IP is recycled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Anyone have an alternative of dealing with issue (1) and (2)? a way that can overcome it for cost saving purposes and at the same time
>    retaining an elastic IP

A load balancer (ALB or NLB) is really your only option. Your statement about health checks preventing Fargate from "sleep" is incorrect though. There is no "sleep" option in Fargate.

If you want something very similar, but with a sleep option, I suggest looking into [AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/).

> 2. If ALB is forwarded to Fargate with IP address, what happen if IP ECS (Fargate) IP got restarted? Will ALB auto detect it or what are
>    the way to detect Fargate IP changes and update back to ALB
>    automatically, and if not, how to handle such situation where the IP
>    is recycled?

ECS integrates directly with the load balancer target group. You configure the ECS service what load balancer and target group you are using, and ECS will keep the load balancer's target group up-to-date with your Fargate IP address(es) automatically.

Comment: Let me rephrase it. Fargate only charges you, by the second, when your container workloads are running. So assuming that my application is only serving people of single countries (and typically during night time there is rarely people visiting the sites, and let's assume if the application typically save around 4-5 hours of Fargate cost per day). However, if I am putting a load balancer in front, the load balancer will do a healthcheck and thus keep the fargate running whenever a healthcheck is perform. The downside of this is that I am paying more than I should. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Not sure if we can turn off the load balancer or set the healthcheck like running 1 per hour, but the whole solution seems to be pretty antipattern, especially if I were to use a costly load balancer for the sole purpose of having a static IP address.

Comment: What are you expecting Fargate to do when you don't have traffic? There is no "sleep" option with Fargate. Fargate doesn't shut down when there is no traffic. A Fargate service runs 24/7 and you are charges for every second of every day. You are not charged only for the seconds that it is serving requests. ECS Fargate Services are a way to run a docker container 24/7 without having to deal with EC2 servers. You seem to be thinking just because it is "serverless" it is "pay per request". If you want "pay per request" you should look at AWS Lambda instead of ECS Fargate.